# Is it possible to create IAM instance profile name by one line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

As reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html, there seem to be many steps to grant permissions to an EC2 instance profile: create a role, put policy to the role, create an instance profile and add the role to the instance profile.

Is it possible to create an instance profile by one line with very generally-used role, such as `AWS S3 Full Access` for example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need 2 lines: 1 line to create the instance profile (`aws iam create-instance-profile`) and 1 line to attach the existing role (`aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile`) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/index.html#cli-aws-iam

As they are command lines, I suppose you can join them with `&&`. Following the AWS documentation example:

```
aws iam create-instance-profile --instance-profile-name CodeDeployDemo-EC2-Instance-Profile && aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --instance-profile-name CodeDeployDemo-EC2-Instance-Profile --role-name CodeDeployDemo-EC2-Instance-Profile
```

Note: if your instance profile is already created you can associate it to as many EC2 instances you want. You don't need to recreate a new instance profile each time.